# Convert bootstrap theme to Joomla

Tags: templates, bootstrap

Apologies if this is a really silly question:
I found a template (on templatemonster) that I really want to use for a Joomla site, but the template is listed as a Bootstrap theme - is it possible (or easy) to convert to a Joomla template.

Many thanks

Rob.

Comment: It's possible, but how easy it is will depend on what needs to be changed and your level of knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way, because you have to code it especially for Joomla. I am sure, that some freelancer is gladly going to do such work for you for a reasonable price.